# ClickOnce error deploying a third party executable

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce, manifest

We are trying to distribute a WPF Application with ClickOnce from a web-server.  I am on Visual Studio 2013.

This application uses an external/"third party" executable.

But when we are downloading clickonce files this error is throw up:

> ERROR SUMMARY
>   Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
>   * Activation of http://domain.com/Our.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
>     + Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly video.player.host.exe.

I have looking for this error and all solutions I have found references to change the manifest on the `video.player.host.exe` application before compiling it.  But in our case, this application is already compiled.

Any idea how can I work-around this ?

Comment: Find video.player.host.exe in your application's app.config file and include that code?

Comment: @GlenThomas What code I should to include?  Anyway I don't have video.player.host.exe in the application app.conf